# Por que o cursor personalizado meu site não está funcionando?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
body {
 cursor: url("http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=51224");
 background-image: url(https://i0.wp.com/media.giphy.com/media/10Hmp1WdHaHmDe/giphy.gif?w=1280&ssl=1);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}
.div-title {
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.label-1 {
 font-family:"Orbitron", sans-serif;
 font-size: 27px;
 color: cyan;
}
header {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.img-random {
 border: 1px solid cyan;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://yourjavascript.com/19500231119/title.js"></script>
 <link rel="icon" a href="https://is.gd/DhDDsG">
</head>
<body onmousedown="return false" onkeydown="return false">
 <div class="div-title">
  <center><label class="label-1">- 0wn3d bY 0xyrh0pus 777 - ^^</label></center>
 </div>
 <header>
  <center><img class="img-random" width="30%" src="https://is.gd/j8KmHb"></center>
 </header>
 <div class="gaf210imvustylez_youtubebox" style="width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe allow="autoplay" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/19s6EbcJ1tI?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=19s6EbcJ1tI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O correto é você utilizar o caminho para uma imagem no CSS: `cursor: url('caminho-para-imagem'), auto;`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou só era pra colocar o vírgula auto; Estou colocando o cursor de forma externa não interna.

Answer (score 3):

Quando se usa uma imagem com cursor é precisa que vc declara tb um *fallback* caso a imagem não seja carregada. Normalmente se usa o `auto`, mas vc pode usar `pointer` ou qq outro valor padrão. Aqui vc pode ver mais na documentação da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#Sintaxe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro problema no seu código é que o cursor só funciona em uma parte da tela, isso pq seu `html/body`, não tem uma altura definida. Para fazer o cursos customizado pegar na tela inteira coloque o `html/body` com `100%` de `height`

Segue o código com o cursos funcionando. **OBS:** Como o *Snippet* do Stackoverflow não aceita imagens ou link em `http` só `https` coloquei outra imagem só pra vc ver que funcionou

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
body {
 cursor: url(https://www.filecluster.com/media/icons/206331.gif), auto;
 background-image: url(https://i0.wp.com/media.giphy.com/media/10Hmp1WdHaHmDe/giphy.gif?w=1280&ssl=1);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;

    /* cursor: pointer; */
}
.div-title {
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.label-1 {
 font-family:"Orbitron", sans-serif;
 font-size: 27px;
 color: cyan;
}
header {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.img-random {
 border: 1px solid cyan;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-title">
 <center><label class="label-1">- 0wn3d bY 0xyrh0pus 777 - ^^</label></center>
</div>
<header>
  <center><img class="img-random" width="30%" src="https://is.gd/j8KmHb"></center>
</header>
<div class="gaf210imvustylez_youtubebox" style="width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe allow="autoplay" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/19s6EbcJ1tI?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=19s6EbcJ1tI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```